# Create Google Cloud Virtual Machine from PHP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

I'm new in cloud environment (Google Cloud)..
Currently I have more than 10 different products of php application software.
I have website where users can register and create their own subdomain name...
Every time users register on my website, I create the VM manually and point the subdomain to the VM manually...

When users registering on my website is increasing, it become very hard to manually add the VM and point the DNS one-by-one

What in my mind is can we automate the process? if possible how to do that?
What is the best method for this?I heard about container and kubernetes...

all information, help and suggestion is appreciated...thank you

Comment: Yes, you can do all of this using the Google SDK for PHP. However, consider the answer from Harsh - Terraform works very well as an automation tool.

Comment: @JohnHanley but if anyone beginner then it is better use Google SDK literally your answer is very simple and i was thinking big big stuff to TF. so for beginner SDK with PHP will easy to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use code as infrastructure like terraform is there.

you can run terraform php.

Refer more about it here : [`https://github.com/aol/terraform-php`](https://github.com/aol/terraform-php)

Where you can set everything and it will also spin up VM behalf of you known as code as infra.

Comment: This is an interesting answer. Using Terraform also allows the automatic teardown of resources. Calling Terraform from PHP makes the whole process very manageable.

Comment: @JohnHanley hello there, Glad to meet you i just checked your profile having 10+ year experience on cloud. i am having some doubt so i have posted question can you please suggest some advice as per your experience https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55157078/which-one-will-be-bertter-gcp-vs-aws-as-per-my-needs......Thankyou so much in advance

Comment: @HarshManvar thanks...seems it is what I need...I should learn a lot using this terraform...

Comment: @JohnHanley automatic teardown of resources --> can you give me more enlightenment on this?it sound interesting... thanks

Comment: keep track of all resources that are created in a test and automatically destroy/free them during teardown.